# How to create slanting text using paint in xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to implement a slanting text in repeat over an image.But I don't know how to implement it. I have attached the sample image.Can any one help me with this?

[image]

Comment: These things you don't design them, sir, you just add images for them, Anyway welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom view and draw the text on canvas. Here is a sample.

Custom view:

```
public class TextOverlay : View
{
    protected TextOverlay(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public TextOverlay(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public TextOverlay(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public TextOverlay(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public TextOverlay(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        // make the canvas Transparent
        canvas.DrawColor(Color.Transparent);

        canvas.Translate(100, 150);

        var paint = new Paint
        {
            Color = Color.Blue,
            TextSize = 18
        };
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);

        canvas.Rotate(-45);
        canvas.DrawText("CANCELLED", 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

Add it to a relative layout on top of the image view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <viewoverlay.TextOverlay
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/textOverlay"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```